# Select-String pattern not matching

Tags: powershell

I have the text of a couple hundred Word documents saved into individual .txt files in a folder. I am having an issue where a MergeField in the Word document wasn't formatted correctly, and now I need to find all the instances in the folder where the incorrect formatting occurs. the incorrect formatting is the string `\#,$##,##0.00\*` So, I'm trying to use PowerShell as follows:

```
select-string -path MY_PATH\.*txt -pattern '\#,$##,##0.00\*'
select-string -path MY_PATH\.*txt -pattern "\#`,`$##`,##0.00\*"
```

But neither of those commands finds any results, even though I'm sure the string exists in at least one file. I feel like the error is occurring because there are special characters in the parameter (specifically `$` and `,`) that I'm not escaping correctly, but I'm not sure how else to format the pattern. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are actually looking for `\#,$##,##0.00\*` then you need to be aware that `Select-String` uses regex and you have *a lot* of control characters in there. Your string should be

```
\\\#,\$\#\#,\#\#0\.00\\\*
```

Or you can use the static method `Escape` of regex to do the dirty work for you.

```
[regex]::Escape("\#,$##,##0.00\*")
```

To put this all together you would get the following:

```
select-string -path MY_PATH\.*txt -pattern ([regex]::Escape("\#,$##,##0.00\*"))
```

Or even simpler would be to use the parameter `-SimpleMatch` since it does not interpet the string .. just searches as is. More [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx)

```
select-string -path MY_PATH\.*txt -SimpleMatch "\#,$##,##0.00\*"
```

Answer (score 1):

My try, similar to Matts:

```
select-string -path .\*.txt -pattern '\\#,\$##,##0\.00\\\*'
```

result:

```
test.txt:1:\#,$##,##0.00\*
```